# Python TCP socket proxy extremely slow

Tags: python, performance, sockets, tcp, proxy

I'm working on a simple proxy in python that takes a HTTP `GET` request from a browser, queries the correct website and returns the data (html, css, photos) to the client. I have it working, but it take an exorbitant amount of time to read the data back from the external web server and send it back to the client. Below is (what I think is) the relevant code:

```
    tempSocket.send(requestToWebpage)

    tempList = []

    while 1:
           print "waiting for data from website..."
           data =  tempSocket.recv(bufferSize)
           if not data:
                break
           else:
                tempList.append(data)

    tempResponse = ''.join(tempList)
    print "closing temp socket..."
    tempSocket.close()

    splitResponse = tempResponse.partition("\r\n")

    response = splitResponse[0] + "\r\n" + "Proxy-connection: close\r\n" + splitResponse[2]

    print "sending results back..."
    newConnection.send(response)
    newConnection.close()
```

The proxy is running on my own machine (as is the client browser), which is Windows 7 64-bit. I have a decent wireless connection to the internet. Currently it takes upwards of several minutes to receive the results of each GET request and transmit it to the client. By watching the print statements, I've noticed that most of the time seems to be spend in the while loop (especially the last loop through it), but the other print messages also take way longer to appear than it seems like they should.

Any ideas on what is going on and suggestions to improve the speed?

Comment: I've tried 2048 and 1024 bytes.

Comment: what I believe is that the server didn't close the socket after it sent the data which corresponds to the very request, so the recv operation was blocking until the server side close the socket. I think you can rewrite `tempList.append(data)` to `newConnection.send(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcus's comment is probably right. The remote server is not closing its connection.

You might be asking for this behaviour, perhaps without even realising it. What is in the request to the server, i.e. what is being sent in `requestToWebpage`? Are you setting a  `Connection: Keep-Alive` header?

Keep-Alive is the default if you are using HTTP 1.1 in the request.

If it is not because of Keep-Alive, you may need to get the Content-Length from the reply and then you'll know how many bytes to read.

Comment: Note that not all replies will have a content-length header. It could also use "chunked" transfer-encoding.  OP should implement chunked transfer encoding and pipelined requests for best performance.